# Design of TextFormField (focusColor and cursorColor)

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey in my App I've got a few TextFormFields. I wanted to define their theme with a theme in MaterialApp(). I've read that the FocusColor is the secondary color, but in my case the focusColor is cyan, although I never defined that. Here is my Theme:

```dart
runApp(MaterialApp(
  theme: theme.copyWith(
    colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(
      primary: globals.primaryColor,
      secondary: globals.highlightColor,
      background: globals.backgroundColor,
    ),
  ),
));
```

And here is my TextFormField:

```dart
TextFormField(
  style: TextStyle(color: globals.darkText, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
    hintText: "Name",
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: globals.backgroundColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    focusColor: globals.highlightColor,
    fillColor: globals.primaryColor,
  ),
  onSaved: (input) => _name = input,
),
```

In addition the cursor is always dark blue, I dont get where to change that color too.
Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```dart
textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(cursorColor: MyColor.kGreen)
```